# What does return; do in javascript?

Tags: javascript, return

I am reading some source code in a HTML5 game and in its animate function there is a `return;` line. I am not sure what it does.

```
function animate() {
  if (somecondition) {

    doSomething;
    return;

  }

  renderSomethingElse();

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

The `return;` line doesn't actually return anything and it doesn't stop the animate function, does it simply stop running the rest of the function except for `requestAnimationFrame(animate);`?

**Edit and conclusion:**

I found that the `return;` line actually exit the anonymous function in the `.forEach` loop in the `animate()` function. That's why it doesn't exit the `animate()` function.

Comment: [__`Return statement`__](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement)

Comment: _"it doesn't stop the animate function"_ What makes you say that - is there more to this question than you're making out?

Comment: return will exit the function immediately, `renderSomethingElse` and `requestAnimationFrame` will not be called.

Comment: @JamesThorpe because normally if it stops running the function I should not be able to continue the game because the animate() function is the only entry for the game to render anything. But even if I meet `somecondition` the game still goes on.

Comment: @newguy Then there's something else going on too, because the code as presented absolutely will prevent further execution of `animate`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an early exit.

```js
function test(){
   alert('works');
   return;
   alert("doesn't work");
}
test();
```

It's an alternative to the following condition:

```
if (somecondition) {
    // ...
} else {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```